# GetMethod when argument comes by reference

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, createinstance, getmethod

I'm creating an instance of an object using reflection and getting the methods within the class of the object, but then the problem comes when I have to use an array of type `Type` to avoid ambiguity problems, here is an example of the code that I'm trying to reach.

```
public class BigClass
{
    public void getSomething(XmlDocument doc, ref CustomObject obj) {...}
    public void getSomething(XmlDocument doc, ref CustomObject obj, string id) {...}
}
```

This code comes from an external assembly (file.dll), and I'm using the next code.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("file.dll");
Type s = a.GetType("FileNamespace.BigClass");
MethodInfo inf = s.GetMethod("getSomething", new [] {typeof(XmlDocument), typeof(CustomObject), typeof(string)});
```

To get the `MethodInfo` of the object that uses 3 arguments, but the variable "inf" comes null, I think because it doesn't find the method for the argument that uses "ref".

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to look for the ref type in order to get the MethodInfo.

```
MethodInfo inf = s.GetMethod("getSomething", new [] {typeof(XmlDocument), typeof(CustomObject).MakeByRefType(), typeof(string)});
```